# Is there a way to connect my Flutter web application to DB located on a server?

Tags: sql, database, flutter, dart

Hello dear fellow programmers.
I hope the title explains my question enough. But just in case...

When I connect to a databse using SQL package in my mobile app, there is really no problem. When I try to use the same code in my Flutter web app, I get this error: "Unsupported operation: Socket constructor".

I've spent a good few hours looking for any kind of solution online, but I couldn't find any. That's why I am asking here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I know some database packages doesn't work with web but some does, you can search sql packages according to web based in [here](https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=sql&platform=web). And I suggest [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor) to use by only personal opinion.

Comment: Would you be able to give me any directions or tips how to connect to my database using Moor?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience to migrate an existing database, generally I used this library to create a new one but it's documentation is really helpful, you can check here for sql database migration: https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/starting_with_sql/